# do you need to import .h files when using delegates?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, protocols, delegation

```
-(IBAction)ok
{
    //send message to the delegate with the new settings
    [self.delegate setHeight:_height Width:_width Mines:_mines];
    [self.delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

the first message to the delegate wouldn't work until i imported ViewController.h, but the second one worked without the import.
if i add -(void)setHeight:(int)h Width:(int)w Mines:(int)m; as required in the optionsViewController protocol will that mean that i no longer have to import the root .h file.

i intend to use delegation to send messages in other parts of the program so i want to make sure i am using it correctly and not importing things when i don't need to.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> if i add -(void)setHeight:(int)h Width:(int)w Mines:(int)m; as required in the optionsViewController protocol will that mean that i no longer have to import the root .h file.

Yes! You could also add it as @optional and it would work (remember to check if the delegate -respondsToSelector: in that case). The whole idea is that your object regularly knows nothing about the delegate object - except that it conforms to the protocol (ie implements the @required and possibly the @optional methods).

Added for clarification (on my phone, which is a pain in the butt):

`//OptionsViewController.h
//this object does NOT have to import
//the calling viewControllers .h file
//which is what I think the OP does`

@protocol optionsViewControllerProtocol;

@interface OptionsViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<optionsViewControllerProtocol> delegate; //should be id, could be UIViewController too, if absolutely necessary (better design to make it id)
@end

@protocol optionsViewControllerProtocol <NSObject>

@required 
-(void) setHeight: (NSInteger) height;
@end

//viewController.h
#import "optionsViewController.h" //necessary to get the protocols definitions

@interface OptionsViewController: UIViewController <optionsViewControllerProtocol>

//.....

Comment: Oh crap. What did it do to the formatting??? Will edit when I get home, or could someone edit in code tags around my code??

Answer (score 0):

If you define your `delegate` property to be of class `UIViewController*`, then the compiler will recognize the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` method without you needing to import anything, since that's a standard method for that class.

For a custom method, i.e. `setHeight:Width:Mines:`, you absolutely need to import the header file, or have it imported somewhere up the import chain.

Example: You have `MyProtocol.h`, and you want `SomeClass` to have a delegate property that conforms to that protocol. If you `#import "MyProtocol.h"` in `SomeClass.h`, you don't need to re-import it in `SomeClass.m`.

```
// SomeClass.h
#import "MyProtocol.h"

@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<MyProtocol> delegate;
@end

//SomeClass.m
#import "SomeClass.h"

@implementation SomeClass

- (void)someMethod
{
    [self.delegate myProtocolMethod];
}
@end
```

Comment: No, if it is specified in the delegate protocol, he absolutely doesn't have to import the .h file :)

Comment: Somewhere up the chain of imports, that file needs to be imported. If he imports a file that imports it, then that will work fine.

Comment: Hmmm... No. The delegate should be of type id<protocolName> - so the methods this object (of unknown or any type) implements are unknown aside from the protocols definition

Comment: Delegates do not *have* to be of type `id` they can be of any type you like.

Comment: No but it is the usual, recommended and most reasonable implementation of a delegate and the basic idea of the concept. Do you usually specify the class for a delegate? Why? And even so the fact that it CAN be id shows you don't need to import .h. A delegate UIViewController<myProtocol> delegate still promises to implement the protocol, so no import of .h necessary

Comment: True, but that doesn't mean it's the best solution for every situation. If you have a situation where you want to call standard `UIViewController` methods, defining a property of that type is perfectly fine. You could duplicate the method declaration, but that's a style choice too. Not sure what version of Xcode you're using, but in 4.6.1 Xcode won't compile id<protocolName> if there's no #import of that protocol declaration. I just tried it.

Comment: The object implementing the protocol always has to import the .h file with the protocols definition - it won't even compile otherwise as you stated. But the OP was talking about importing the delegate objects .h file to the object that delegates.

Comment: Answering to the edit of your answer: I don't think that is what the OP asked